# Find the sum of squares of the real solutions to $\sqrt[3]{5x - 2} = \frac{1}{5}(x^3 + 2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, radicals

> Find the sum of squares of the real solutions to $\sqrt[3]{5x - 2} = \frac{1}{5}(x^3 + 2)$

I tried applying Viete's formulas after raising everything to the third power, however computing $\sum_{k = 1}^9 x_k^2$ also includes complex solutions, yet the problem only asks us for real solutions.

One can easily spot that $x_1 = 2$ is a solution, and Wolfram Alpha states the other two solutions are $x_2 = \sqrt{2} - 1$ and $x_3 = -\sqrt{2} - 1$, therefore the sum should be 10. However, how could I prove this mathematically?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt[{\mathrm{3}}]{\mathrm{5}{x}−\mathrm{2}}=\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{5}}\left({x}^{\mathrm{3}} +\mathrm{2}\right) \\ $
$\Leftrightarrow\mathrm{5}\sqrt[{\mathrm{3}}]{\mathrm{5}{x}−\mathrm{2}}={x}^{\mathrm{3}} +\mathrm{2} \\ $
$\mathrm{Let}:\:{a}=\sqrt[{\mathrm{3}}]{\mathrm{5}{x}−\mathrm{2}}\Rightarrow{a}^{\mathrm{3}} =\mathrm{5}{x}−\mathrm{2} \\ $
$\mathrm{From}\:\mathrm{the}\:\mathrm{given}\:\mathrm{equation}\:\mathrm{we}\:\mathrm{have} \\ $
$\begin{cases}{\mathrm{5}{a}={x}^{\mathrm{3}} +\mathrm{2}}\\{\mathrm{5}{x}={a}^{\mathrm{3}} +\mathrm{2}}\end{cases} \\ $
$\Rightarrow\mathrm{5}\left({a}−{x}\right)={x}^{\mathrm{3}} −{a}^{\mathrm{3}} =\left({x}−{a}\right)\left({x}^{\mathrm{2}} +{ax}+{a}^{\mathrm{2}} \right) \\ $
$\Leftrightarrow\left({a}−{x}\right)\left({x}^{\mathrm{2}} +{ax}+{a}^{\mathrm{2}} +\mathrm{5}\right)=\mathrm{0} \\ $
$\Leftrightarrow{a}={x}\:\mathrm{or}\:{x}^{\mathrm{2}} +{ax}+{a}^{\mathrm{2}} +\mathrm{5}=\mathrm{0} \\ $
$\mathrm{But}:\:{x}^{\mathrm{2}} +{ax}+{a}^{\mathrm{2}} +\mathrm{5}=\left({x}+\frac{{a}}{\mathrm{2}}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} +\frac{\mathrm{3}{a}^{\mathrm{2}} }{\mathrm{4}}+\mathrm{5}\neq\mathrm{0} \\ $
$\Rightarrow{a}={x}\Leftrightarrow{x}^{\mathrm{3}} =\mathrm{5}{x}−\mathrm{2}\Leftrightarrow{x}^{\mathrm{3}} −\mathrm{5}{x}+\mathrm{2}=\mathrm{0} \\ $
$\Leftrightarrow{x}=\mathrm{2},{x}=−\mathrm{1}\pm\sqrt{\mathrm{2}}\Rightarrow\mathrm{Sum}\:\mathrm{of}\:\mathrm{squares}=\mathrm{10} \\ $

Answer (score 1):

Here $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x^3+2}{5}.$ Then $\displaystyle f^{-1}(x)=(5x-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

So we have to find number of solution of $\displaystyle f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$

Which equals $f(x)=x\Longrightarrow x^3+2=5x$

(Because inverse function is symmetrical about $y=x$ line)

So $\displaystyle x^3-5x+2=0\Longrightarrow x=2\,\ ,-1\pm \sqrt{2}$

Comment: $f(x)=f^{-1}(x) \implies f(f(x))= x$ not $f(x)=x$

Comment: @SamarKamboj And?

Comment: Your method works here but it will not work everywhere. For instance if $f(x)=\sqrt{7-3x}$, then $f^{-1}(x)=(7-x^2)/3$ and solving $f(x)=x$ only gives us the solution $x=(-3+\sqrt{37})/2$ but we have other solutions like $x=1$ or $x=2$.

Comment: @nonuser if $f(x)$ is continuous and increasing over the domain then only $ f(x) =x$ is the solution of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$.  Here $f(x)$ is increasing over the entire domain, hence it works.

Comment: @SamarKamboj, Well, considering the other inverses in other domains does not get all the answers necessarily . The problem with your argument in looking for answers of $f(x)=x$ instead of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$, is that you assume that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ intersects only on the line $y=x$, but actually it is the case only if they have some fixed points in their domain. Now if we look at the example $f(x)=\sqrt{7-3x}$ with $f^{-1}=(7-x^2)/3$, we see that $x=1$ is a solution for $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ but it is not a fixed point.

Comment: @SamarKamboj, For more details have a look at this Note by Ng Wee Leng and Ho Foo Him which I barrow the example from: https://www.atm.org.uk/journal/archive/mt228files/atm-mt228-39-42.pdf

Comment: @DyakoSoltanian Thanks for the clarification.